# Avatar on YouTube Vanced is not clickable

Tags: youtube

I am using YouTube Vanced (not because of removed ads, but because of old UI, and also it does not force you to update, I could use the original YouTube, but because of last I don't) version 15.05.54. The problem is that on my Android tablet (Android 6.0), the avatars in comments are clickable and I can go to someone's channel, but using exactly the same on my Android phone (Xiaomi Redmi 7A, Android 10) I can't.

What's the problem? I remember, that earlier it was working, but now it doesn't. Maybe my Android version is too high?